# Variable not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function. etc

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and I have a script to retrieve some OS properties.  It starts...

```
$ntfsDisableLastAccessUpdate = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem -Name NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate  | Out-String).Split("`n")[2] -replace "\r",""
```

This seemed to work running it locally, but is producing the following error when run elsewhere:

```
    Invoke-Expression : The term '���$ntfsDisableLastAccessUpdate' is not 
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
that the path is correct and try again. 
At line:1 char:62 
+ 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (���$ntfsDisableLastAccessUpdate 
:String) [Invoke-Expression], CommandNotFoundException 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Co 
mmands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: _Looks_ like an encoding issue. How was the script saved? Also would need to see how you are invoking it remotely just to be safe.

Comment: You were correct!  Your tip was enough to get my mind rolling.  I have no idea how it got in there, but some weird invisible character had been encoded into the script, even though the file was in UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`���` is most certainly representative of an encoding issue. That would mean the issue is with how the file was being saved and how it is being read. The latter is an important part which is missing.

I don't see why you would be using `Invoke-Expression` for your script locally or not. `Invoke-Expression` works on strings so does that mean you are reading in the script file as a string?

Either way [from the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35437414/variable-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet-function-etc?noredirect=1#comment58580142_35437414) it looks like you were able to remove the offending characters and move on.